# Dynamical System problem

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

PLS HELP ME. I have a problem with this exercise given by the professor for home. It's about Lyapunov equation and autonomous systems. Here it is:

Prove that if the state of equilibrium $x^*=0$ $(x^*\in\mathbb{R}^n)$ of the system:

$x(k+1)=e^A x(k)$  with $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

is asymptotically stable then even the equilibrium state $x^{**}=0$ of the system:

$\dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)$

is asymptotically stable.

I thought I could apply the step invariant transformation for an autonomous system and since it should preserve the response it should be asymptotically stable. But i'm not sure...
Hope someone of you can help me, thanks in advice!

Comment: Seems to be the same as this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954042/dynamic-systems

Comment: yeah I just refreshed and deleted the past post hoping now more people can see it.

Comment: But you already had a comment giving the full answer, don't you want to think about the problem?

Comment: I already tried that way without get anything near an answer. In fact I asked u if u can be more precise or give a litttle more information because it's a little bit generic and I donb't think Jordan canonical form can help me...

Comment: @Ambrogio123 I think what John B has in mind is the fact that asymptotic stability for the discrete system $x(k+1) = M x(k)$ holds if and only if $M$ has eigenvalues with magnitude less than $1$ and for the continuous system $\dot x = Ax$ if and only if $A$ has eigenvalues with negative real part; the proof of this fact typically relies on Jordan normal form. With that established, it suffices to note that $M = e^A$ has eigenvalues with magnitude less than $1$ if and only if $A$ has eigenvalues with negative real part.

Comment: ty @BenGrossmann will think about it and ty for the specification... I didn't realize that's a good way to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what tools you have available, but here is an approach using the definition of asymptotic stability.

Consider trajectories corresponding to the common initial state $x(0) = x_0$.
For any $k = 0,1,2,3,\dots$ and $t \in [k,k+1]$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\left\|e^{tA} x_0\right\| &= \left\|e^{(t-k)A} \cdot e^{kA} \cdot x_0\right\|
\\ & \leq
\|e^{(t-k)A}\| \cdot \left\|e^{kA} \cdot x_0\right\|
\\ & \leq 
e^{\|(t-k)A\|} \cdot \left\|e^{kA} \cdot x_0\right\|
\\ & \leq  e^{\|A\|} \cdot \left\|e^{kA} \cdot x_0\right\| = e^{\|A\|} \cdot \|x(k)\|.
\end{align}
$$
In other words, we have $0 \leq \|e^{tA}x_0\| \leq e^{\|A\|} \cdot \|x(\lfloor t\rfloor )\|$. If $\lim_{k \to \infty}\|x(k)\| = 0$, then it follows from the squeeze theorem that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \|e^{tA}x_0\| = 0$, which is to say that the continuous time system is asymptotically stable.

Comment: don't think there are limits to resolve the problem and even if it's more a matematic resolution I think it could be good. In other case I will try the other one resolution give it to me by @John B (if the prof doesn't accept that way)

Comment: @Ambrogio123 As I said, this uses the definition of asymptotic stability. The definition of "asymptotically stable" usually involves a limit